# When to use Groovy versus a shell script in Jenkins?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I was watching this video about Jenkins:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BIry0cepz4

He mentions that shell scripts have many advantages over using Groovy, to do custom work, in a Jenkins build process.

Apparently the sandbox that Jenkins uses to run the Groovy has some sharp limits?

Where can I find more information about this? When do I give up on Groovy and switch to a shell script?

Comment: Your question is too broad and pretty opinionated - these kind of questions are off-topic to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: Having built out a Jenkins environment over a year, I ended up with a mix of Groovy and shell scripts. Each has its strengths, so why limit yourself by choosing one over the other? I find Groovy syntax much nicer than shell scripts, but sometimes it was easier to call a shell script from Groovy. Use what works.

Comment: Dan, your answer amounts to "Start with Groovy and add in shell scripts where you need them" which sounds like a good rough rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment from Szymon says this a broad question to answer. And there is no one stop shop that list all the pros and cons of each. It will rather build up based on the use case and the experience that you encounter.

> Apparently the sandbox that Jenkins uses to run the Groovy has some
>   sharp limits?

This is due to the fact that Jenkins enforces certain security measure,so as to not call any method that can perform malicious or unhealthy stuff inside your infrastructure. If you really need to use certain listed libraries, you/jenkins admin need to white-list the class by approving it. Check out the link below:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/

Now, shell script does comes very handy but its not always hunky-dory, on everything.

> When do I give up on Groovy and switch to a shell script?

To me, it depends on what i am trying to achieve. Select it based on the which one makes it more easier.